# Is there a place to find images for a corporate websites

Tags: image

I am looking for a place that would be able to provide images such [as](http://www.mckinsey.com/~/media/McKinsey/dotcom/client_service/client_service.ashx) [these](http://www.mckinsey.com/~/media/McKinsey/dotcom/About%20us/about22.ashx) which I can use in a corporate website layout.  Google search results typical images of bunch of strangers sitting and pretending to be doing work and looking over happy about what they do.  Instead, I am looking for just some creative artsy looking images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out any of the stock photography sites:

- http://www.gettyimages.com/
- http://www.shutterstock.com/
- http://www.fotosearch.com/
- http://www.istockphoto.com/
- http://www.sxc.hu/

Great place to check out images that are good for use in "corporate" like materials. Websites, brochures, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It'd be better if you hire a designer, because in a corporate website, most of the things of this quality are copyrighted, and you need to pay to get those (and that too you cant be sure if you could get what you need, right away). Maybe check `shutterstock.com , istockphoto.com`